# Spring MVC - JSTL <c:url> - Cannot resolve controller URL

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

Anyone can help me with this problem?

[I can't resolve the value of the script tag. (">)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DjRs.png)

[CartResources:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phjfw.png) // [Controller.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSO0m.png) // [viewProduct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrmyI.png)

Comment: share your code here

Comment: I have added some pictures that may help you. I am 100% sure that the code is fine. Thanks !

Comment: it might be your spring configuration problem,should you code and do not add pictures directly here!